# How to launch Canvas LTI Consumer request from ASP .Net Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, lti

I am new with Canvas LMS. I have some configuration XML (including launch URL, private and secret key) of Canvas LMS. I have my own .Net application and i want to create LTI request on button click event from my .Net portal which will create an launch LTI request to Canvas Portal using XML and keys. Could anyone provide any help document or code, so that i can achieve it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about LTI but I found this guide for **.NET LTI Launch**

[Part 1: Connect To Canvas](https://community.canvaslms.com/groups/canvas-developers/blog/2016/09/13/net-lti-project-part-1)

[Part 2: Launch Request](https://community.canvaslms.com/groups/canvas-developers/blog/2016/10/14/net-lti-project-part-2-launch-request)

[Part 3: OAuth](https://community.canvaslms.com/groups/canvas-developers/blog/2016/09/20/net-lti-project-part-3-oauth)

Hope this can help you in some way.